# Angular 8: error TS2322: Type 'Observable<CustomType>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<CustomType[]>'

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

I have an angular component and I get the error 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<CustomType[]>'. I'm fairly new to Angular and not able to debug this.

The following is the component:

```
export interface SearchGroup {
  type: string;
  list: any[];
}


export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

  
  options: Observable<SearchGroup[]>;
  returnData = [];
  suggestions: SearchGroup[] = [];
  

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    

    this.suggestions = [{
      type: 'Type 1',
      list: [{a:1},{b:2}]
      },{
      type: 'Type 2',
      list: [{c:3},{d:4}]
      },
    ];

    this.options =  this.form.get('formControl')!.valueChanges
        .pipe(debounceTime(300),
            startWith(''),
            switchMap(userInput => this.filterList(userInput))
        );

  }

  filterList(value) : SearchGroup[] {
    let filterValue = (value || "").toLowerCase();
    let returnVal =  this.suggestions
                         .map(group => ({type: group.type,list:this._filter(group.list,filterValue)}))
                         .filter(group=> group.list.length > 0);
    return returnVal;
  }

  _filter(list,filterValue){
    return list.filter(item=> item['id'].toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

With this, I get the following error :

```
 error TS2322: Type 'Observable<SearchGroup>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<SearchGroup[]>'.
      Type 'SearchGroup' is missing the following properties from type 'SearchGroup[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

Comment: You're using `switchMap(userInput => ...)` on a result that is not an observable. Switchmap is for flattening observables. You just need a map instead of that switchMap.

Comment: @Silvermind, this worked. Thanks a lot!